# How can I generate axis having values 1/1/11 1/1/12 1/1/13

Tags: tableau-api

In tableau how can we generate order date axis like 1/1/11 1/1/12 1/1/13.  I am getting order date like 2011 2012 2013

Comment: The order is the same and Tableau's choice of formatting is better. Why change it? If you want to, the issues is merely how to format dates not how to generate the right sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but you can format the axis of any measure.

Ex: start with an empty view. Drag sales to Rows. Right click and drag Order Date to Columns and select the 'Day' option (continuous...green pill). Right click on the Order Date pill and select format...on the axis tab, update the date scale option to mm/dd/yy

Answer (score 0):

In tableau on date axis right click on that and go into format.

change into **custom** as per mm-dd-yy

[custom date wise graph]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsRCo.png